# How do you install a LetsEncrypt SSL Certificate on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, lets-encrypt

Since Heroku is read-only and does not allow sudo, what do I need to do to be able to install the LetsEncrypt.org certificate on their server for my app?

If I have already set `config.force_ssl = true` does that matter?

Comment: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/01/12/lets-encrypt-with-a-rails-app-on-heroku/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I read the blog post in the first answer here, but I didn't want to pollute my code-base with ACME urls & logic. So I did something similar, but used DNS domain validation ...

With certbot, specify DNS as your preferred challenge:

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns
```

After a couple of prompts, certbot will tell you to deply a DNS TXT record to validate your domain:

```
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.www.codesy.io with the following value:

CxYdvM...5WvXR0

Once this is deployed,
Press ENTER to continue
```

Your domain registrar probably has its own docs for deploying a TXT record. Do that, and go back to certbot and press ENTER - Let's Encrypt will check the TXT record, sign the cert, and certbot will save it for you to upload to heroku.

[See my own blog post for more detail](http://groovecoder.com/2017/01/03/letsencrypt-heroku-dns.html).

---

**Here are two bash functions that you can use to *automate* the process for you**

```
function makessl {
    sudo certbot certonly --manual --rsa-key-size 4096 --preferred-challenges dns -d ${1}
    sudo heroku certs:add --type=sni /etc/letsencrypt/live/${1}/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/${1}/privkey.pem
}

function renewssl {
    sudo certbot certonly --manual --rsa-key-size 4096 --preferred-challenges dns -d ${1}
    sudo heroku certs:update /etc/letsencrypt/live/${1}/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/${1}/privkey.pem
}
```

> They take an arguement for the domain name and as long as you run them from within your `heroku app folder` you will not have to specify an `--app NAME`
>
> **Example:** `makessl www.domain.com`
>
> **Example:** `renewssl www.domain.com`

---

Combine this is [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297029/eric)'s answer and you're good to go:

`heroku certs:auto:enable`

Comment: **This is a *GREAT* answer** that removes the need of updating the `response tokens`

Answer (score 5):

FYI, Heroku now offers automated certificate management w/ Let's Encrypt if you run a paid dyno. You can enable it with:

```
heroku certs:auto:enable
```

More info:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management

Answer (score 2):

## Edit: This answer no longer applies.

It was written before Heroku implemented native support for LetsEncrypt. Leaving the rest for posterity, but this is no longer necessary. Use [@Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072714/37168) now.

---

### Installing the initial certificate

You can use certbot in manual mode to generate the challenge response, modify your site to return that response, then finally complete the certbot manual process.

[See this blog post by Daniel Morrison](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/01/12/lets-encrypt-with-a-rails-app-on-heroku/), or the linked answer under Certificate Updates below, for more details.

### Certificate updates

As @Flimm mentioned, and as is mentioned in the linked blog post, you'll have to update this every 3 months until Heroku provides better support for LetsEncrypt. You can make that process smoother (no code changes to upload) using an environment variable as described in this answer (Node/Express but the concepts are the same): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199581/37168

#### Sabayon

There is a GitHub project that can automate all of this for you by setting your Heroku environment variables. It's a tiny webapp you install as another Heroku app that in turn configures your primary app. I haven't tried it yet but am planning to use it instead of updating my cert next time: https://github.com/dmathieu/sabayon

Answer (score 1):

The [default recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) of Heroku is SSL using Server Name Indication 
(SNI), which is free. Since you already obtained your certificate and key, you can add them by:

```
heroku certs:add <cert>.pem <key>.key
```

If you need to support legacy browser clients which do not support SNI use the [Herkou SSL Endpoint](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/ssl) addon which costs $20/mo:

Add that addon by running

```
heroku addons:create ssl:endpoint
```

And then add your LetsEncrypt.org certificates:

```
heroku certs:add <cert>.pem <key>.key
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll to manually redo this regularly, Let's Encrypt certificates only last 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

the best way can be to  assign the new ssl domain(that starts with https) to your domain which automatically overrides the non-http domain

Answer (score 0):

I created a certbot plugin that uses the Heroku CLI to automate authentication and installation of Let's Encrypt certificates: https://github.com/gboudreau/certbot-heroku

I only have an example that uses the php-nginx Heroku buildpack, but reading that example and finding the equivalent for other buildpacks should be easy enough.
Pull Requests are welcome to help others!