# Forwarding https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, dns, lets-encrypt

Trying to get

https://example.com

To not refuse the connection, to show my website, and to redirect to:

https://www.example.com

Without having to switch my DNS hosting to DNSimple or adding another service provider.

My domain was purchased on GoDaddy. DNS is on GoDaddy as well, set up as shown below.

My app is hosted on Heroku, using a Let's Encrypt certificate, that I installed following [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199581/4117788)

Currently using `Helmet`+`express-enforces-ssl` to force hsts.

I have read the following info:

[Heroku SSL on root domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701549/heroku-ssl-on-root-domain) ; [Heroku SSL Endpoints](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) ; [The Limitations of DNS A-Records](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains)

The last of which states:

> (...) applications requiring SSL encryption should use the
>   ALIAS/ANAME configuration on the root domain. Subdomain redirection
>   will cause a browser error when the root domain is requested over SSL
>   (i.e. https://example.com).

Which seems to be my problem (?).

How do I set this up on GoDaddy?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this without switching to DNSimple?

Comment: What's your exact question? How to get a LE certificate? Or how to redirect all non-www requests to the www subdomain?